# Register Multiple implementations of the same contract : one in Chilcontainer and one in the Parent

Tags: unity-container, ioc-container

I am trying to register multiple implementations of the same interface like this :-

```
**DLL A: Module.cs**
_container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo1>("Foo1");
```

---

```
**DLL B: Module.cs**
var childContainer = _container.CreateChildContainer(); //childcontainer
childContainer.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo2>("Foo2");
```

---

```
**DLL A: Resolve IFoo for Foo2** (But, resolving IFoo for Foo1 is fine)
var foo2 = container.Resolve<IFoo>("Foo2"); //Error
```

*Note: The container which I receive here is the "childcontainer".
Have checked the hashcode.*

**Error:**

> A first chance exception
>   of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll
>
> Additional information: The current type, IFoo, is an interface and
>   cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

---

**But**, it works, if I do the registration of Foo2 in DLL A just after Foo1 i.e. like this :

```
_container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo1>("Foo1");
_container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo2>("Foo2");
```

Is `Registration (Register) and Resolution (Resolve)` dependent upon scope & assembly ? I want the 1st approach to work. Any idea ?

Comment: Well, I tried an example with the info I have. So, how do you share IFoo definition betwen Dll A and Dll B? Where is IFoo definition? How do you pass container to Dll B? How do you pass childrenContainer to Dll A? I will edit my post once I have all the info I need to replicate your exmaple.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the next example and is working for me. Just be carefull with assembly references and namespace includes.

```
**Dll A

Public  Interface Ifoo

 End Interface
```

---

```
**Dll B


 Public Class Class1

        Public Shared function registerOtherType(container AS IUnityContainer) As IUnityContainer
            Dim c As IUnityContainer = container.CreateChildContainer
            c.RegisterType(of Ifoo, foo2)("2")
            Return c
     End Function


    End Class

    Public Class foo2
        Implements Ifoo

    End Class
```

---

```
**Dll C

    Public Class foo
        Implements Ifoo

 End Class

    Sub Main()
        'init()
        'Dim manager As IClasificationManagement = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(Of IClasificationManagement)()
        'manager.SwapDescrition("1", "2")
        'Console.WriteLine("Operacion Realizada")
        'Console.Read()
        Dim container As IUnityContainer = New UnityContainer()
        container.RegisterType(Of Ifoo, foo )("1")
        dim child As IUnityContainer = Class1.registerOtherType(container)
        child.Resolve(of Ifoo)("2")

    End Sub
```

Comment: There is `no DLL C` if you notice in my question.

Comment: So, how do you share IFoo definition betwen Dll A and Dll B? Where is IFoo definition? Because if you pass container to Dll B from Dll A you must include Dll B into Dll A and if IFoo is in Dll A and you use it in Dll B you must include Dll A in Dll B. You end with a circular reference.